# MonoDevelop failed to start on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: lts, shared-library, mono

After starting:

`$ monodevelop --no-redirect`

```
Linux 5.19.0-35-generic #36~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri
Feb 17 15:17:25 UTC 2 x86_64

FATAL ERROR [2023-03-04 18:02:26Z]:  MonoDevelop failed to start. Some
of the assemblies required to run MonoDevelop (for example
gtk-sharp)may not be properly installed in the GAC.

System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
'MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeApp'  threw an exception. ---> 
System.TypeInitializationException:  The type initializer for
'MonoDevelop.Ide.Fonts.FontService'  threw an exception. ---> 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
'Pango.FontDescription' threw an exception. --->

System.DllNotFoundException: libpango-1.0.so.0 assembly:<unknown
assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null) 
at(wrapper managed-to-native)
Pango.FontDescription.pango_font_description_get_type()   
at
Pango.FontDescription..cctor () [0x00000] in
<481c3522f1e0423eab2879b04a5661a7>:0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at MonoDevelop.Ide.Fonts.FontService..cctor () [0x0001e] in
<0d5fa71f3b5e459095de129b1f163448>:0  
--- End of inner exception
stack trace ---   at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdePreferences..ctor () [0x001b4]
in <0d5fa71f3b5e459095de129b1f163448>:0    
at
MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeApp..cctor () [0x0001b] in
<0d5fa71f3b5e459095de129b1f163448>:0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   
at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run (MonoDevelop.Ide.MonoDevelopOptions
options) [0x0017c] in <0d5fa71f3b5e459095de129b1f163448>:0    
at
MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup. Main (System.String[] args,
MonoDevelop.Ide.Extensions.IdeCustomizer customizer) [0x000f4] in
<0d5fa71f3b5e459095de129b1f163448>:0 
FATAL ERROR [2023-03-04
18:02:26Z]: An unhandled exception has occurred.  Terminating
MonoDevelop? True System.TypeInitializationException: The type
initializer for 'Pango.FontDescription' threw an exception. 
--->
System.DllNotFoundException: libpango-1.0.so.0 assembly:<unknown
assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)   
at (wrapper managed-to-native) 
Pango.FontDescription.pango_font_description_get_type()   
at Pango.FontDescription..cctor () [0x00000] in
<481c3522f1e0423eab2879b04a5661a7>:0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:

System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
'Pango.FontDescription' threw an exception. ---> 
System.DllNotFoundException: libpango-1.0.so.0 assembly:<unknown
assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)   
at (wrapper managed-to-native) 
Pango.FontDescription.pango_font_description_get_type()   
at
Pango.FontDescription..cctor () [0x00000] in
<481c3522f1e0423eab2879b04a5661a7>:0 
 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

installed packages:

```
- gir1.2-coglpango-1.0/jammy,now 1.22.8-3build1amd64[zainstalowany,automatycznie] 
- gir1.2-pango-1.0/jammy-updates,now
   1.50.6+ds-2ubuntu1 amd64 [zainstalowany]
- libcogl-pango20/jammy,now 1.22.8-3build1 amd64 [zainstalowany,automatycznie]
- libgtk2.0-cil/vs-buster,now 2.12.45-0xamarin19+debian10b1 amd64
   [zainstalowany]
- libgtk2.0-cil-dev/vs-buster,now 2.12.45-0xamarin19+debian10b1 amd64 [zainstalowany,automatycznie]
- libpango-1.0-0/jammy-updates,now 1.50.6+ds-2ubuntu1 amd64
   [zainstalowany]
- libpango1.0-0/jammy-updates,now 1.50.6+ds-2ubuntu1
   amd64 [zainstalowany]
- libpango1.0-dev/jammy-updates,now
   1.50.6+ds-2ubuntu1 amd64 [zainstalowany]
- libpango3.0-cil/jammy,now 2.99.3-4build1 amd64 [zainstalowany]
- libpangocairo-1.0-0/jammy-updates,now 1.50.6+ds-2ubuntu1 amd64
   [zainstalowany] 
- libpangoft2-1.0-0/jammy-updates,now
   1.50.6+ds-2ubuntu1 amd64 [zainstalowany]
- libpangomm-1.4-1v5/jammy,now 2.46.2-1 amd64 [zainstalowany,automatycznie]
- libpangoxft-1.0-0/jammy-updates,now 1.50.6+ds-2ubuntu1 amd64
   [zainstalowany]
- pango1.0-tools/jammy-updates,now 1.50.6+ds-2ubuntu1
   amd64 [zainstalowany,automatycznie]
```

Comment: Please format that output into something readable.

Comment: I found old libraries in the path /usr/lib:/usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so, /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so in the old version and after removing them the program starts